# How to ignore untracked files when I switch to a branch?

Tags: git, github

I created a repository with two branches. The first branch contains a Unity project and a `.gitignore` file that generates GitHub. The other branch has latex files to create the documentation and other `.gitignore` file that is generated by GitHub too.

When I am working in the `doc` branch and I compile my latex files, they generate a `main.syctex.gz` file which is ignored by my `.gitignore`. Everything until here is ok. However, when I type `git push -u origin doc` and I switch the `doc` branch to the `master` branch, the file ignored (`main.syctex.gz`) appears in the `master` branch.

I know that if I type `git clean -f -d` I can clean the Doc folder that contains `main.syctex.gz` in the `master` branch. But, I would be grateful if someone can tell me another option to fix this problem.

Comment: Are there any files you want ignored in one branch and **not** in the other? It might be better to have the same gitignore settings across both, just using the union of the current separate settings.

Comment: Yes! In the `mater` branch I have a `.gitignore` for ignoring files from Unity and in the `doc`branch I ignore files from Latex.

Comment: Yes, but I'm saying could you not just ignore both in both branches? And don't revert legitimate edits.

Comment: are you saying that I place both `.gitignore` in both branches?

Comment: You can only have one file of that name, but I'm suggesting you combine their contents to a single shared version.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked!

Comment: It sounds like you are using separate branches to hold what should really be in separate repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be two have two different workspaces (working trees) for the same cloned (cloned only once) repository.

See [`git worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309): you can then work on both branches without worrying about the checkout part.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CrisGmz of course, ignoring both set of files in one .gitignore works too, but I prefer avoiding data leaking from one branch to another, ie avoiding that one branch has to known about files from another branch.

Comment: You are right. I'll take it into account for future repositories. Thanks again!